# swift compiler error - xcode 8.1 new project

Tags: swift, xcode8

I have created a new swift project using xcode 8.1 and when I tried to build it, it is showing me 21 errors which are related to the "UIKit" framework.

What is missing in my xcode? I tried with different xcode versions like xcode7.3.1, xcode8.1, but the same issue happened.

[image: Please check attached image with error list.]

Comment: you need to provie more info. Seems that you have some objective c code somewhere.

Comment: hi Irfan, I have created new swift project, even I restart mac machine and again i tried to create new project and build still i m getting same errors.

Comment: can you show project navigator?

Comment: Check your frameworks in the project settings, and make sur it's using `UIKit`

Comment: Hi Irfan, I have already attached one screenshots.

Comment: Hi, Jimmy James, when ever we create new swift project or objective c project UIKit frame work added automatically right?. I tried to create new project from different mac book and build it build properly and same project i tried to open on my mac book again i got same 21 errors.